# Find the volume between the planes $y=0$ and $y=x$ and inside the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I understand we can approach this problem under the change of variables:

$$x=au; y= bv; z=cw$$

Thus we get:

$$V= \iiint_R \,dxdydz = abc\iiint_S \,dudvdw$$

At this point the ellipsoid has become a sphere. Thus we could use spherical coordinates to compute the volume.

My issue is with the extremes of the integral; concretely with the $\theta$ angle. I would set up the integral like this:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi / 4} d\theta \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} d\phi \int_{0}^{1} dr$$

But the stated solution is:

$$\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1} (a/b)} d\theta \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} d\phi \int_{0}^{1} dr$$

My extremes make sense to me; it is just about visualizing  a sphere and two intersecting planes. But $\tan^{-1} (a/b)$ confuses me.

What's wrong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change variables, the plane $y=x$ becomes $bv=au.$  So your upper limit for $\theta$ isn't $\arctan 1=\pi/4$ but $\arctan(a/b). $

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add more details? I still do not know how to get $\arctan(a/b)$. (I know it has to be really easy but I do not get it)

Comment: The line $y=x$ becomes the line $v=au/b$, which has slope $a/b.$  The angle between the $u$-axis and the line is $\arctan a/b$, so that's the angle $\theta$ must go to.